# Simulation Waveform in Intel Questas_fse/Quartus II doesn't update outputs

Tags: fpga, modelsim, quartus, questasim

I'm attempting to run Quartus II (
Quartus Prime Version 21.1.0 Build 842 10/21/2021 Sj Lite Edition) on linux Pop OS 21.10.
I fail to produce result on output from Questas simulation run from the Simulation Waveform Editor.

## Project

### Settings

- I have created a new project with these options
  [image]
- I selected the `5CSEMA5F31C6` board

### Files

#### .bdf file :

[image]

#### .vwf file :

[image]

#### Simulation Setting

Notice the removal of `-novopt` to supress error message claiming deprecation of the option. Refuse simulation if left into script but is inserted in script by default. This is the step I'm most unsure about.

```
onerror {exit -code 1}
vlib work
vlog -work work ok.vo
vlog -work work Waveform1.vwf.vt
vsim -c -t 1ps -L cyclonev_ver -L altera_ver -L altera_mf_ver -L 220model_ver -L sgate_ver -L altera_lnsim_ver work.ok_vlg_vec_tst
vcd file -direction ok.msim.vcd
vcd add -internal ok_vlg_vec_tst/*
vcd add -internal ok_vlg_vec_tst/i1/*
proc simTimestamp {} {
    echo "Simulation time: $::now ps"
    if { [string equal running [runStatus]] } {
        after 2500 simTimestamp
    }
}
after 2500 simTimestamp
run -all
quit -f
```

## Step to reproduce

- press "functional simulation" [image: Run functional simulation] from Simulation Waveform Editor
- wait for simulation to finish
- wait for read only result window to appear

## Results

### expected

[image]

### actual

[image]

## conclusion

I failed to produce output on `C`.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the simulation settings, replace the `-novopt` option with `-voptargs="+acc"`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).